Proving that SU(2) matrices are the the exact group that rotates Pauli vectors
I'm watching an introductory video series on spinors, and I'm stuck at a proof that shows the (half) rotations of Pauli vectors correspond to $ SU(2) $ matrices.
Here’s the relevant part of the video: Spinors for Beginners 6: Pauli Vectors and Pauli Matrices.
We are trying to prove the following:
Given $ W = AVB $, where $ V $ and $ W $ are Pauli vectors, $ W $ is a rotation of $ V $ and $ A $ and $ B $ are some matrices, show that $ A \in SU(2) $ and $ B = A^\dagger $.
Properties of Pauli vectors (as said on the video, some are relevant only in the later parts of the proof):

A Pauli vector is Hermitian: $ V = V^\dagger $.
A Pauli vector is traceless: $ tr(V) = 0 $.
Rotating a Pauli vector does not change its determinant:
$ \det(V) = -||\vec{v}||^2 = -(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) $.

The Proof on the video: (adjusted a bit)
The first part of the proof is trying to show that $ W = AVB $ implies $ W = AVA^\dagger $. Here’s the reasoning:
$W = AVB$
$W^\dagger = (AVB)^\dagger$ (a Hermitian transpose on both sides)
$W^\dagger = B^\dagger V^\dagger A^\dagger $ (using the reverse-distributive property of Hermitian transpose)
$W = B^\dagger V A^\dagger $ (since $ W^\dagger = W $ and $ V^\dagger = V $, properties of Pauli vectors)
From this point, the proof in the video makes the following leap:

We can use this as a hint to assume that the $ B $ matrix should equal $ A^\dagger $.

I.e. $ AVB = B^\dagger V A^\dagger \implies B = A^\dagger $
This seems like a significant logical leap, and I’m having trouble convincing myself that this step is valid. While I trust the result is correct, I feel like I must be overlooking something or misunderstanding the reasoning.
Could someone explain why it is valid to conclude $ B = A^\dagger $ here, or fill in any missing steps in the logic?

Try $B = 5 A^\dagger$. You have only used 1 property so far. What stops this kind of shenanigan using the properties you have?

Perhaps helpful: Taking the determinant of $AVB=B^\dagger V A^\dagger$ we can conclude that
$\det(AB)=\det(A^\dagger B^\dagger)=\overline{\det(AB)}$
so $\det(AB)$ is real.

As stated, this is simply wrong. My general suggestion is to learn by reading. The quality of math physics textbooks is variable but they are still more reliable than online videos.
